# How do i output the 2 latest users in SQL?

Tags: sql

How do I select the latest persons or ID from a row?

for example, if we have.

```
1: Eric
2: Matt
3: Adam
4: Dylan
5...
6...
7...
```

How do i output nr. 6 and 7 only using SQL PHP? `LIKE SELECT * FROM table WHERE users`

Comment: `ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 2`?

Comment: Latest, as in the two highest ID values?

Answer (score 0):

If you want the last two based on the first column, you can use:

```
select t.*
from t
order by col1 desc
fetch first 1 row only;
```

This is *standard* SQL.  Not all databases support the `fetch` clause.  Some use `select top` or `limit` or even more arcane syntax.